# GStreamer Android Tutorial Build Failed

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, gstreamer

I'm running into number of problems while trying to run GStreamer Android Tutorials on Windows. I'am new to Android NDK so this could be a really simple issue but I couldn't figure out how to solve it.

These are the build error messages when I try to build the project

> Build command failed.
>
> Error while executing process
>   D:\gstreamer\android-ndk-r19b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r19b\ndk-build.cmd
>   with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
>   APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\xxx\xxx\gst-docs-master\examples\tutorials\android\android-tutorial-1\jni\Android.mk
>   NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\xxx\xxx\gst-docs-master\examples\tutorials\android\android-tutorial-1\jni\Application.mk
>   APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0
>   APP_PLATFORM=android-16
>   NDK_OUT=C:/xxx/xxx/gst-docs-master/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-1/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj
>   NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\xxx\xxx\gst-docs-master\examples\tutorials\android\android-tutorial-1\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\lib
>   NDK_APPLICATION_MK=jni/Application.mk GSTREAMER_JAVA_SRC_DIR=src
>   GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID=D:/gstreamer/gstreamer-1.0-android-universal-1.15.1
>   GSTREAMER_ASSETS_DIR=src/assets APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false
>   LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>
> process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>
> *** Android NDK:  Assertion failure: SYSROOT_LINK is not defined    .  Stop. Open File

When I clicked the "Open File" it has sent me to gstreamer-1.0.mk file and the lines below.

> ifdef SYSROOT
>       SYSROOT_GST_INC := $(SYSROOT)
>       SYSROOT_GST_LINK := $(SYSROOT)
>
> else
>       ifdef SYSROOT_INC
>           $(call assert-defined, SYSROOT_LINK)
>           ifdef SYSROOT_LINK
>               SYSROOT_GST_INC := $(SYSROOT_INC)
>               SYSROOT_GST_LINK := $(SYSROOT_LINK)
>           endif
>       else
>           SYSROOT_GST_INC := $(NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT)/$(TARGET_PLATFORM)/arch-$(TARGET_ARCH)
>           SYSROOT_GST_LINK := $(SYSROOT_GST_INC)
>       endif endif

I think the problem is about SYS_ROOT as mentioned in the error message but I don't know what "SYS_ROOT" means or "NDK_PROJECT_PATH" is.

I have added gstAndroidRoot to gradle.properties so while building this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 10, Android Studio 3.5. This worked for me.

1. Download the entire gstreamer android studio tutorial directory from [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-docs/).
2. Open Android Studio -> Open an existing Android Studio Project
3. Open the entire android tutorial directory `examples/tutorials/android` as a project
4. Once the project is open change the view on the left side of the screen to `Project`
5. Right click near `local.properties`. Right click -> file -> New -> File
6. Create a new file called `gradle.properties`
7. In the new `gradle.properties` file copy and paste the below code.

   ```
   # gstAndroidRoot can be set to point to the unpacked GStreamer android top-level directory
   # containing each architecture in subdirectories, or else set the GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID
   # environment variable to that location
   gstAndroidRoot=/gstreamer_android_binaries
   ```

   **Note:** Change the `gstAndroidRoot` variable to your file path where you downloaded the gstreamer binaries and unzipped them. Gstreamer can be downloaded from [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/) for Android.
8. Now we need to set up NDK directory. Make sure you download and have NDK enabled under SDK tools.
9. This will download the latest NDK version. However gstreamer currently will  not build with the latest NDK. We need to download NDK Revision 18b from [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases). If you do not use NDK version 18 you will likely get an error `Android NDK: Assertion failure: SYSROOT_LINK is not defined . Stop. Open File`
10. Unzip the downloaded NDK 18b directory.
11. Take the unzipped `android-ndk-r18b` directory and move it to where the ndk folder is under `AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk`
12. You should now have two folders within `Android\Sdk\ndk`. `20.0.5594570 (or latest version)` and `android-ndk-r18b`
13. In android studio go to File -> project Structure
14. Under Android NDK location point to the NDK 18 directory. Example: `C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\android-ndk-r18b`
15. Connect a phone with USB debugging and run!
16. If you get an error on the phone stating it is for an older version of android. Go back to Android Studio and switch to `Android View` on the left side of the screen. Under `Gradle Scripts` select the `build.gradle` for the appropriate tutorial. Change the `compileSdkVersion 29`, `minSDKVersion 15`, and `targetSDKVersion 29`.